# Data of this type has inbuilt behaviour, and cannot be added to a model in this way: System.Int64

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

This error:

```
Data of this type has inbuilt behaviour, and cannot be added to a model in this way: System.Int64
```

happens only when the following line sets up a surrogate type of long for protobuf-net to use when serializing objects with the TimeStamp type.

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(TimeStamp),false).SetSurrogate(typeof(long));
```

The TimeStamp class has the following explicit operators defined:

```
public static explicit operator TimeStamp( long timeStamp)
{
    return new TimeStamp(timeStamp);
}

public static explicit operator long( TimeStamp TimeStamp)
{
    return TimeStamp.Internal;
}
```

So why doesn't it accept long as the surrogate type for TimeStamp?
Prior to starting to try protobuf-net, hand-written serialization already
uses long as the surrogate for TimeStamp when serializing/deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

At the current time, the surrogate behaviour is expecting to map to "message" types (in protobuf terminology). Being able to map that to a primitive such as `long` seems an unusual case. It is most likely possible for me to tweak the code to make that work, but: simply - that wasn't the intended use-case for this feature, hence it doesn't currently support that (*messages* and primitives have significant differences in terms of what is stored).

BTW, depending on how many of these you have, you could just do:

```
public TimeStamp Foo {get;set;}

[ProtoMember(n)]
private long FooValue {
    get { return (long)Foo; }
    set { Foo = (TimeStamp)value; }
}
```

Comment: I ran into this exact issue today, and wanted to give a +1 vote to enabling this feature.  We are using strongly-typed identifiers in our database layer, and it would be nice if we didn't have to add a shim property to every protobuf serializable class that contains a property of an identifier type.  Each of these identifier types expose explicit conversion to/from int.

Comment: Same here. In my case, "public readonly record struct Username" - string op

Comment: @sharpc this seems like a different thing, but: a more complete example would help - that isn't the end of a record definition, etc